# 7.toBinayString does not work in scala REPL, but with val k=7 it works

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

```
scala> val s = 7.toBinayString 
<console>:7: error: value toBinayString is not a member of Int
       val s = 7.toBinayString 
                 ^

scala> val k = 7
k: Int = 7
scala> k.toBinaryString 
res44: String = 111
```

Since val k = 7 and 7 are identified as Int, not as RichInt or java.lang.Integer I don't see why they are handled differently.

Why is there a difference?

Comment: @PrimosK: If somebody corrects the headline, the question will become useless. ;)

Comment: Hehehe :) I didn't saw that either.. :)

Comment: This should be marked as "Best of" of StackOverflow.

Comment: @userunknown I was just about to do that when I saw your comment below the edit box. :)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Because of the spelling mistake.

```
toBinayString -> toBinaryString
```

[image]

Comment: No, that's impossible! The repl needs a "REPL suggests: "

Comment: @userunknown: Do you know auto-completion?

Comment: @Antoras: `val s = 7.to`<kbd>tab</kbd>` 
toByte     toChar     toDouble   toFloat    toInt      toLong     toShort    toString`

Comment: @userunknown: Ok, this should be improved in the REPL.

Comment: @userunknown Actually, paulp did add a REPL suggests. I wonder where it went... it probably won't work with implicitly added methods, though.

Comment: @KimStebel: I think I have at least the better facepalm:  http://home.arcor.de/hirnstrom/images/minusch-facepalm-medium.jpg

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?